# How to fix the error 'There has been an overflow or underflow in GC memory pressure.'

Tags: .net

I am using C# for programming!

We have three load balance servers, it was working before, however we started getting below error now days for our PORTUGUESE website only and If I check the task manager it is an network service (`W3WP.exe`) taking lots of memory. Once I kill that process from task manager it works fine and again tomorrow it starts coming.

> There has been an overflow or underflow in GC memory pressure. The possible cause is unbalanced AddMemoryPressure and RemoveMemoryPressure calls

I have already checked my SQL connection in project, its all fine and are closed properly.

Please suggest what can be the reason for this above error as its now started annoying us.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not your connections, but something else is holding references. Are you disposing of other expensive resources? Are you unregistering events when done with objects?

Comment: The error message is *very* specific, go hunting for calls to GC.Add/RemoveMemoryPressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt killing w3wp.exe was a good idea: it's the IIS worker process. Have a look at http://blog.whitesites.com/w3wp-exe-using-too-much-memory-and-resources__633900106668026886_blog.htm for some assistance.

Comment: Thanks any Idea why it is only coming for my Portuguese website?

Comment: None whatsoever, to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

Use a profiler, such as [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) to see what resources are not released. Look for the objects that are holding most memory.

Comment: Thanks any Idea why it is only coming for my Portuguese website?

Comment: Not really. Possibly some localization code is not releasing resources?